# A non-cloud local calendar for Android?

Tags: calendar

Is there any way to have and use a local calendar on Android?

I would like to use it on the Android phone and open the file (vcs, ics, anything) on my laptop sometimes.

I have not found any applications that deal with local calendar files stored on the SD-card of the phone. I have found only numerous cloud applications so far.

Is there any app that can open and edit local calendar files on Android?

Comment: You can use the stock calendar and load the _ICSSync_ sync provider app. Disable Google and any other cloud service providers, enable this one, and set it to a path on your SD card. So long as you've disabled the cloud providers correctly, a sync operation will just sync calendar data to your local ICS repository, rather than sending it to a remote service. (It's free for 20 days, then requires an inexpensive purchase - the free version seemed to work for me).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Etar - Open source calendar](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ws.xsoh.etar) app is what we needed.

See its source at [GitHub](https://github.com/Etar-Group/Etar-Calendar).

Comment: Note to readers. The answer when it was written and accepted had suggested a different solution which was valid for than available Android versions. That solution later on was superseded by the currently mentioned solution and it does not work for Android versions from 2012 year.

Answer (score 1):

https://market.android.com/details?id=de.mgsimon.android.andtidwiki

and a tiddlywiki.html + calendar plugin

Comment: Okay. Why? How does this help?

Comment: because you have a non cloud calendar then? or did you vote it down because it is no native app? a app is a app, either native or html5 ;)

Answer (score 1):

I was recently recommended *ColorNote*, which keeps its calendar data separate from the stock calendar storage, and so (presumably) is less likely to accidentally send your private data to cloud services you do not wish to use.

It has a very clean month-view, but the day view is quite limited - you can only see the first ten characters of each item (at least on my tiny Samsung Galaxy Europa) and appointment times cannot be set, only appointment reminders. So for me - a substantial calendar user - it's not sufficient.

I've tried a *lot* of calendar applications, and I am seeing that the vast majority of these interface with the stock calendar - the UI is very good, and I should think it saves developers a ton of work. Hence, you need to be careful to keep the Google account sync options disabled - turn it on and your data will be send to the cloud in short order - i.e. game over if you are opposed to this. (The google account cannot be removed from the phone, as other applications "require" it).

Personally, I am considering a good calendar app that works with the stock Calendar, then rooting the phone and installing a firewall. My guess is that I can limit the applications that use Google services to a minimum (i.e. Market/Play) so I can have reasonable confidence I am not going to accidentally use their Calendar cloud. I appreciate this faffing isn't of interest to everyone - but I'd argue the process of **not** using the cloud really ought to be easier!

Answer (score 1):

Please check my Android App called [Calendar Manager](http://www.zoks.net/solutions/calendar-manager).

It creates a local calendar database which does not sync to any cloud storage. You can use other calendar apps to manage your appointments, since the databse integrates nicely into the Android system.

However, you can synchronize the database with your PC using software like MyPhoneExplorer.

NOTE: It only works on Android 4.x+

Answer (score 0):

You could try [CalApp](http://www.appbrain.com/app/calapp/air.CalApp).

CalApp is a iCal file browser and Calendar application. It allows you to import events,todos,journal entries from iCal,iCalendar, ics, vcs formatted files to your smartphone and browse them selectively.

It has a built-in Calendar to store your notes, appointments, todo list etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think Business Calendar may fit your needs. Although it has cloud sync, you can choose to use local only.

Comment: Can you give more info on this? I'm trying the free version of _Business Calendar_, and the UI is very good, but it seems to me that it requires a calendar attached to a sync provider of some kind. Of course there are local sync provider apps available (e.g. ICSSync), but I can't see any option in Business Calendar that specifically offers a local calendar.

Answer (score 0):

I believe user's zoks.net application is exactly what is required to answer the question.

If you also want the new local calendars synced between your phone and other locations (your own http/webdav/caldav/ftp server for example) you might want to consider [CalendarSync](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.icalparse&feature=related_apps). It has a hefty price tag, imho. But it does what it says it does. And is still being developed as of today. (I'm not affiliated with the app's developers at all).

CalendarSync can also create local, standard android calendars. And all such calendars can always be accessed by other, normal calendar applications such as [aCalendar](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.withouthat.acalendar) or [Digical](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.digibites.calendar).

If you don't want any sync functionality zoks.net [Calendar Manager](http://www.zoks.net/solutions/calendar-manager) is an easy to use solution.

Answer (score -1):

My android 2.2 (samsung galaxy fit) has two installed calendar provider.

When i create a new calender-entry i can choose to put it into my own lcal calender or into the "xxx@googlemail.com-calender" in the cloud.

I am not shure whether this is samsung specific or android standard.

Comment: It appears there is a setting in menu-calendars, where it will let you tap on the calendar to set sync and visibility on/off. Is this what your phone has?

Comment: In the calendar app and in the android-settings i havent found such a menue.